# Mysql query inverse IN or search an item from array

Tags: mysql

I have two table in my datebase. first one is tools table:

```
 ------------------
|  id  |  toolName |
|  1   |  ...      |
 -------------------
```

and user table:

```
|----------------------------|
|  id  |  name     |  tools  |
|  1   |  ...      |  1,2,4  |
|----------------------------|
```

User can have many tools in the same time. so `user.tools` is `array`. I want to get user (or users) who used one tool (by tools id).

I thought this code would work, but it didn't work:

```
select * from user where toolID in (user.tools)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`find_in_set()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select *
from user
where find_in_set($toolID, tools) > 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try different data model with following tables:

```
Tools
Users
UserTools
```

The UserTools will be a junction table (read about **many-to-many** relationship)

Otherwise you should use `find_in_set` (as user Bohemian pointed)
But i suppose it may be not a efficient solutions because of string comparison (correct me if I am wrong)